# What should I know / concern when creating a index with 30 - 40 or more columns?

Tags: elasticsearch

As mentioned in subject, I want to create a index with 30-40 or even more columns (mostly keyword and number).

What should I concern or know about this situation? Is it bad for performance? Is it bad for elasticsearch cluster stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each document in Elasticsearch, there are some limitations to the number of fields and how they are organized.

You can check these limitations in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) (this might be different based on ES versions). These limitations can be changed and include the total number of fields that you can have (default to 1000) and the maximum depth for a field (default to 20).

Based on the documentation defining too many fields might not be a good idea, especially if you have many documents:

> Defining too many fields in an index is a condition that can lead to a mapping explosion, which can cause out of memory errors and difficult situations to recover from

Also, be aware of the dynamic fields that you put into the document. Every new field will add a new definition to the document mapping settings.

In your situation, Considering the default maximum number of fields which is 1000, having 40 fields (column?) won't be a problem. Unless you have too many inner objects that might exceed some other mapping limitations like `index.mapping.nested_fields.limit` or`index.mapping.nested_objects.limit`. And try to fix your document structure (mapping) before adding them.